# How Load codeigniter CSS, Images, Js

Tags: php, codeigniter

For a new project what are the steps to link external css, js, images in codeigniter

My Folder Structure is
css -> style.css
js ->

I have web application, considering internet resources I did

(1) Add the URL for autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'text', 'form','string', 'download', 'html', 'security', 'cookie');
```

(2)Add the base URL in config.php File

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:60/hostel';
```

(3)Remove index.php from config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

(4)In my view file I added style

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
```

(5)Created a .htaccess file for the project and added

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|CSS|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

(6) In Application Folder .htaccess file I added

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I want to linke the style, js files and images. But It is get an error

```
http://localhost:60/hoste/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: where are you putting css, image and js. exact directory path

Comment: It is in application->css->style.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put them in application directory just create a assets directory in your project root directory. assets/css, assets/images, assets/js

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
```

Comment: I did not previous error but now: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:60/dashboard/"